# Python Selenium click login

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, click

I'm having a tough time clicking the login button on a website and I'm startin to think it blocking my request. I'm using selenium and I'm getting

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException message and it just opens the link.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

s = Service('C:\chromedriver.exe')

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chromeOptions)

list_data = []



#PATH = "C:\chromedriver.exe"
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://virtualracingschool.appspot.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
'Login'))).click()
```

[image: site and error]

I've tried referencing the selenium documentation regarding find element by tag name, css selector, and xpath (not sure how to get the other xpath when I click copy xpath it pastes (//*[@id="gwt-debug-dataAndSocialContainer"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDmhy.png)/div[2]/div/div[2]/a/span)